# Slight issue with Adjustable Sticky footer CSS

Tags: html, css

Following is a piece of CSS code for my sticky footer. There is only one issue; whenever I open the site in a maximized window, then the sticky footer works fine if there is not too much content. However, when I open it in a restored down window, then the footer ends up in the middle of the page. All I want to do is to keep my footer after the content of the body. If the content does not fill the whole screen, then footer should appear at the bottom and if the content fills more than the screen, the footer should appear at the bottom after the content. Kindly let me know how to modify the CSS to resolve this issue.

```css
.footy {
    height: 100px;
    position:absolute;
    color: #eaeaea;
    background-color: #333333;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width:100%;
    margin-left: -8px;
}

.footin {
    padding-top: 45px;
    width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="footy">
<div align="left" class="footin"> LLC. 2012 All rights reserved &copy; </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just kindly let me know how can i stick my footer to bottom when `position:static;` because one functionality is being accomplished by doing that but it doesnot work if the content is very less on the page and hence the footer doesnot stick to bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding a `min-height` and `position:relative` to your main container where you placed your footer.

edited:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>You site Title</title>
    <style>
        body,html{margin:0;padding:0;}
        #wrapper{position:relative;min-height:700px;background-color:#ccc;}
        #footer{position:absolute;bottom:0;background-color:#ff4345;height:100px;width:100%;}
    </style>
</head>

 <body>

  <div id="wrapper">

   <div id="header">
     <!-- header code-->
   </div>

   <div id="content">
     <!--your content goes here-->
   </div>

   <div id="footer">
     <!--your footer code goes here-->
   </div>
  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

you can try this way to finish up your project.The idea is you main container should have the height of the whole view port and your footer will be positions relatively with this container at bottom.

Comment: when i changed the position to position:relative it results to show the footer at the top of the page not at the bottom..

Comment: just kindly let me know how can i stick my footer to bottom when  position:static; because one functionality is being accomplished by doing that but it doesnot work if the content is very less on the page and hence the footer doesnot stick to bottom

Comment: it did the trick try adding a min-height and position:relative to your main container where you placed your footer.